# Get Witcher2 to run by fixing list of dependancy issues

Tags: drivers, graphics, games, dependencies, intel-graphics

I installed Witcher2 from a .sh file and when I try to run the game, I am presented with a long list of dependancy problems:

```
./witcher2 failed to start due to the following dependancy problems:
    linux-gate.so.1 => (0xf77d2000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 (0xf771a000)
    libSDL2-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libSDL2_image-2.0.so.0 => not found
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7710000)
    librt.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf770b000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf766b000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0xf7537000)
    libopenal-eon.so.1 => ./libopenal-eon.so.1 (0xf74cc000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf73e4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf739e000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7381000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7365000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf71b6000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0xf718d000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0 (0xf7174000)
    libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0xf7161000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf715d000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf7156000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xf7153000)
    libxcb-glx.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xf713b000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xf7135000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0 0xf7131000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-present.so.0 (0xf712c000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0xf7125000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0xf7103000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxshmfence.so.1 (0xf7100000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf70fa000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2 (0xf70ea000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf77d4000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf70d0000)
    libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xf70a8000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0xf70a4000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0xf709c000)
```

I wanted to install the Intel Graphics Driver for my computer using their installer, but it wouldn't install; it said:

> Package: intel-linux-graphics-installer
> Error: Dependency is not satisfiable:libgtk-3-0 (>=3.16.2)

So I looked for `libgtk` to install, and it gave me another dependency error, which I downloaded. That one also gave me another dependency error. This went on until I gave up after trying to install like 9 .deb files (all which kept giving me successive dependency errors).

My laptop is Lenovo G50-80 on 4th Gen core i3 and HD Graphics 4400.
Hardware is just as it was when I bought it.

[Screenshot with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LdGG.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for improvements to the question - more friendly over here than at SO :)

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't fix it, as I've seen these rabbit holes you staring at go pretty deep before, but I would start with doing available updates on your system. I can see in the screenshot you left that update manager has some for you to do.

Frequently the problem with these rabbit holes that go this deep aren't going to be easy to fix with updating one deb file at a time. They could even potentially cause some unexpected errors. Check your repositories, odds are you are pulling updates from either a newer repository that has regressions, or an older repository that isn't as up to date as you need to run the game and install the driver.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you. In case that does not work when I try it, which Linux distro has the best driver support that you would recommend I download? I mainly use Windows, but I was thinking of playing the game on Linux which is less resource intensive so I could squeeze out as much performance as possible (and also get used to linux)